# How to hide a pages div if an attribute is blank on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On my show page from a scaffold I have the following design:

```
<div id="show_location_main_area" class="grid_24">
    <p>
       <strong><%= @business_location.website %></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong><%= @business_location.address %></strong>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="grid_5">
     <%= gmaps(@json) %>
</div>
```

If `@business_location.address` is **blank** I don't want to show this part on the page:

```
<div class="grid_5">
    <%= gmaps(@json) %>
</div>
```

How is this done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following conditions -

```
unless @business_location.address.nil?
unless @business_location.address.empty?
if @business_location.address
```

Example -

```
<% unless @business_location.address.nil? %>
    <div class="grid_5">
        <%= gmaps(@json) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: To expand on this, it's generally better to check for `blank?`, rather than `nil?` or `empty?`. The reason is that `nil?` checks for only nil values ( `"".nil? # false` ). `empty?` is a Ruby method that works on Strings, Arrays, and Hashes, and returns true if the length of any of them == 0. However, `nil.empty?` throws a NoMethodError. `blank?` is a Rails method which works the same as `empty?`, but works on any object. It also returns true if the object only contains whitespace. Example: `"\n".blank? # true` and `"\n".empty? # false`. Bottom line is that `blank?` is more versatile.

Comment: @bricker Thanks for the clarification. I will use blank? instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't include it at all:

```
<% if @business_location.address.present? %>
    <div class="grid5">
        <%= gmaps(@json) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you need the `.grid5` `<div>` there for your HTML/CSS to work:

```
<div class="grid5">
    <% if @business_location.address.present? %>
        <%= gmaps(@json) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```